# Disable Function Key Hotbar on UEFI Lenovo Laptop

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100S running Windows 10. With most Lenovo laptops, the BIOS contains an option that determines whether pressing the f1-f12 keys by themselves sends the actual function key signal or whether it performs the "hotbar" actions (adjust volume/brightness, disable radios, etc.). However, this laptop uses UEFI rather than BIOS and doesn't seem to have an option for fn key behavior in the UEFI (nor have I found any UEFI updates).

Some models support a "fn lock" by holding escape and pressing the fn key. As far as I can tell, mine does not support this.

Some Lenovo keyboard drivers contain a control panel entry that include an option for swapping fn key behavior. If mine supports this, I am unsure how to access it.

Does anyone know how to swap the fn key behavior on the Lenovo Ideapad 100s with Windows 10?

Comment: I'm thinking you have triple-checked, but just in case, when you are in the Configuration screen in your UEFI settings, there is no option for "Hotkey" mode? (keyword: hotkey - I don't believe this feature is referred to as fn keys or function keys)

Comment: And, just in case..... https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht104064

Comment: hi @Shoeless, thank you for your response. i've just checked again, and none of the configuration options remotely resemble "hotkey" or "function key" or anything that could change keyboard behavior.

Comment: my UEFI configuration screen looks much more "modern" than the pictures in that article (i.e., has less-harsh colors, smooth fonts, and even some gradients in the menus).

Answer (score 0):

***Just a workaround:***

Attach a second (perhaps very small) keyboard in order to use the F-keys. As a standard, the fn key will not be locked.
Use the main keyboard for fn-keys, and the second one for the F-keys.

p.s.:
In any case, always check again the options offered by Lenovo at https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht103044-how-to-use-the-function-keys-without-pressing-fn-in-windows-8110, perhaps another way works now that has not worked before?